# PHP PDO_ODBC() or ODBC(unified)?

Tags: php, database, pdo, odbc

Here is the question:

I have old foxpro database that are used by my co. ERP. And I need to make a web page using PHP to display some data.

But I am not sure what I should use. In a recent project I used PHP::PDO_ODBC functions.
But one of my co-worker uses PHP::ODBC(unified) functions in one of his project.

1-What is the differences between the two?

2-Is one of them more secure?

3-Just like the MySQL functions are deprecated, is either PDO_ODBC or ODBC(Unified) deprecated??

4-Will an old FoxPRO DB or even older DB type work on both?

Thanks for any help regarding this!

Comment: I did give the answer to MichaelHiroshima but if anyone have more information on this please share. everything is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer all your questions but there are a few things I learned recently. I just had to use an MS Access database in a project which is what brought me on to PDO and ODBC. I originally used ODBC, but I think the PDO is more recently updated and offers better error reporting. I couldn't get ODBC to report any query errors other than that it had failed. In the end I had to go back to using ODBC because I couldn't find the equivalent of a lot of these functions [listed here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php) in PDO (I'd already started my project in ODBC). For basic operations querying the database I found no difference between the two. 
You've probably already seen this but it looks like foxPRO works fine with PDO
[as seen here](http://www.somacon.com/p251.php)
(actually the bottom of this page has a link to the ODBC driver for foxPRO

Comment: Thank you! Just like you said it didn't answer everything but provided me with most of the answers I was looking for. For the rest your answer provided a good starting point for some research.